# Knowing how to define functions at the right time

Tags: c, function, parameters

This is a "weird" question, as it confuses me. I have been learning C, and I realized I had a question not in my C book.

When starting a function, like `int main()` or `void name()`, HOW do I know what to put in the brackets... like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or just `int main()`.

It is a stupid question, but I wouldn't know WHEN to use what when programming. Resources to online links would be helpful.

Thanks, and sorry for stupidness.

Comment: This is a very basic question, but it's not stupid at all.  Don't apologize for trying to learn something new!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables you pass to a function are its inputs or (sometimes) its outputs.  For example, if you wanted to write a function that adds two integers and returns their sum, you could define

```
int sum(int m, int n) {
  return m + n;
}
```

The `main()` function is a special case, because it operates on the command-line arguments that are supplied to the program.  In most languages, `main()` takes an array of strings, with one word from the command line in each string.  In C, it also takes an integer that represents the number of words that were entered on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

In your specific question about `main()`, you will need the arguments inside the parentheses when you want to refer to the command line args that were passed in. You might be confused about the different ways to declare functions. As a starting C programmer, you should always use `int func(int a, int b)` declaring your return type, function name, parameters, and parameter types on the same line. Don't let the other syntaxes confuse you- most are there for historical reasons, and when you know enough to answer know why they're there, you'll know enough to answer this question on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the correct signature is `main(int argc, char *argv[])`, it's not unusual to see `int main()`.  This works because *C is not particularly strict about checking the signatures of external functions* (there's no way it could be; when you call an external function in C, you're just giving a pointer to the function and an argument list; there's no way it can really check that you're using that function the way it was originally defined.)

So this will work too:

```
int main(int argc) { return 0; }
```

Even this will:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], int foo) { return 0; }
```

just don't expect any meaningful value to show up in `foo`.